What happens if the seller of an index ETF goes bankrupt?
Say I buy an index ETF offered by BlackRock and BlackRock goes bankrupt after a while. The companies that are part of the index are still fine (so the index per se is still fine) but the seller of the ETF is gone. Is my money gone too? Or is there some regulation/guarantee from a backing entity (e.g. insurance company)? And is that different according to ETF's domicile?

Comment because I don't know for sure, but I assume the actual assets are held in trust at arms-length from the management company.  In the case of bankruptcy, the assets would be transferred to a new company under some arrangement or sold and paid back to the shareholders.  No doubt some management fee would be applied but I'd guess you'd not lose everything.

https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/need-help/answer/what-happens-to-my-money-if-vanguard-become-insolvent. It's the same for all FCA regulated entities.

Generally after a purchase is delivered to you you couldn't care less if the seller goes bankrupt. Many (most) times you'd be buying ETF shares on the secondary market from entities completely unaffiliated with the manager at all.
When you're buying a ETF unit, you're buying a share of a fund, you are not lending money to the fund manager. The fund is a separate entity from its manager, holding its (fund's) assets separately, and is regulated and audited (at least so we want to hope, check the prospectus).
If there's fraud involved, the fund doesn't actually do what it says it does in the prospectus, or the fund manager is embezzling from the fund, that would be a different story.
If the manager goes out of business, usually its portfolio gets bought by someone else, including the fund management contracts.
